# How to redirect http to https for IP and domain on Apache2

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Apache2 web server running on Ubuntu 12.04. The domain of the website that I am hosting works fine, and if you go to the http version instead of the https version, it automatically redirects to the https version of the domain.

However, if I go to the http version of the ip address of the domain, it does not automatically redirect to the https version of the ip address.

There is nothing in the .htaccess or httpd.conf file.

I have tried adding a redirect for the ip specifically in the .htaccess file, but it does not work properly and the when I visit the domain, it says there are too many redirects.

I have a default-ssl file and website file in the sites-enabled folder. The default-ssl has virtual host config for port 443 and the ServerName

The website file has virtual host config for port 80, but no ServerName

Both files have the same DocumentRoot

How do enable the https redirect for the ip address as well, not only the domain?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a rewrite rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, websites don't allow you to browse them using their IP addresses. They will do a 301 redirect to their domain address instead. This is for search engine optimisation, as having multiple addresses point to the same host may confuse search engines into thinking they are different sites, causing the sites to unnecessarily compete with each other for page ranking.

Since you already have HTTPS redirect on your domain address, why don't you redirect your IP address to your domain address? The domain address will then redirect to the HTTPS site. You can do this through .htaccess, or through a server-side page processor like PHP.